# Nuxt.js's meta property in layout file is not work in middleware

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Nuxt.js's meta property in layout file is not work .

I want to create a middleware that judge user's role satisfy layout's role.

so, I write layout component. This includes allowed role(`roles`).It's below.

`layout/default.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-app class="primary">
    <v-content>
      <nuxt />
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  middleware: ['authorized'],
  meta: {
    roles: ['driver']
  },
}
</script>
```

also I write page component.

`pages/sample.vue`

```
<template>
  <div>hoge</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'default.layout',
  data() {
    return {}
  }
}
</script>
```

also I write middleware. It's below.

`middleware/authorized.js`

```
export default async function({ redirect, store, route}) {
  let userInfo = null
  userInfo = await store.getters['auth/userInfoObject']

  // Search metaData that has meta property.
  const metaDataIncludeRole = route.meta.filter(metaObject => {
    return 'roles' in metaObject
  })

  // Judge user's role includes it.
  const isAllowed = metaDataIncludeRole[0].roles.some(role => {
    return role === userInfo.roleType
  })

  if (!isAllowed) {
    // Redirect any 
  }
}
```

But in middleware,

`route.meta` is below.

```
Array []
```

why roles property is not included? Please tell me.

Url used for reference is below

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1687

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3751

Answer (score 4):

From any component or layout:

```
this.$nuxt.$options.context.route.meta;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm Sorry.

It seems that meta proerty can't be used in layout file.

I confirmed from this following PR。

> **from pages only, into the $route.meta data**
>
> https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/3751